# How do you get through Hell on an iPad?

Tags: candy-box

I was playing Candy Box on an iPad, and suddenly realized that I needed the `i` and `k` keys to navigate through the map. How can I do this?

Comment: bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: @DavidStarkey I don't have one :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a few things:

- Save your game, take it on a computer, beat hell, save again and come back to your iPad.
- Bind a bluetooth keyboard.
- If you're using Android, install [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIm9yZy5wb2NrZXR3b3Jrc3RhdGlvbi5wY2tleWJvYXJkIl0.), then go to the Settings app, Personal, Language & Input, then tap on the sliders icon next to "Hacker's Keyboard." Scroll down to "Input mode settings", then enable "Use permanent notification." Go back to Candy Box, slide open the notification pane and tap on the Hacker's Keyboard entry, then i/j to your heart's content.

Comment: "I was playing Candy Box on an iPad"...."If you're using Android"....Something tells me its not android

Comment: It's still helpful for those who read the question later who are using Android.

Comment: @DavidStarkey What Adam said ↑